# MySQL throwing syntax error while trying to alter a table

Tags: mysql, alter-table, alter

I have been trying to alter a table to include a date column with default value of CURDATE() but MySQL is constantly throwing syntax error. Now, I have checked syntax for altering a table from several sources but I believe I do not have any syntax error. When I remove the default value part, the query runs fine but for some reason it cannot add a default value for the date column. I don't know why that is the case.

The code:

```
mysql> describe test;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| col1  | int          | YES  |     | 0       |       |
| col2  | varchar(100) | YES  |     | hello   |       |
| col3  | varchar(5)   | YES  |     | T       |       |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMN col4 DATE DEFAULT CURDATE();
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CURDATE()' at line 1
mysql>
```

Edit: My MySQL version: 8.0.31

Comment: The error is on the last token before the one indicated by the expression _"the right syntax to use near"_. Here that token is `DEFAULT`. Not sure if it helps.

Comment: @axiac I have looked up the syntax on many websites and found no problem with my syntax. This is how you set a default value for any column, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has to be like this now:

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMN col4 DATE DEFAULT (CURRENT_DATE);
```

Note the parenthesis, or (curdate())

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Is it a new modification to the syntax or was it in effect for some time?

Comment: I think it part of the v.8 spec:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html